# Parsing a JSON object (list of object) through Javascript and loop in it?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jsp

Ok, I know there's something wrong but I can't understand what.

I read an ArrayList of Service (in JSON mediatype) from a web service that I wrote.
Going to that address returns me the json string.

Now I'm trying to make a web page for showing that values and seeing the changes making to the page a request every 3 secs.

How can I parse it, or use it? Read lot and more and I'm still to the start..

[Is not possible to pass this object to the JSP and parse, loop and everything with JSTL? That would be awesome!]

Here the js code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "/MyApp/rest/display", success: function(data){
        var objs = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(objs, function(i,service) {
            $("#service").append('<p>'+service+'</p>');
        });
    }, dataType: "json"});
}, 3000);
</script>
```

I've a `<div id="service">`

**EDIT:**
Almost there!

Now I've this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "/myApp/rest/display", success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,service) {
            var cont = 1;
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.setAttribute('id', "service"+i);
            $("#service"+i).html('<p>'+service.serviceId+" "+service.queue.lastNumber+'</p>');
            document.getElementById("services").appendChild(newdiv);
            cont++;
        });
    }, dataType: "json"});
}, 5000);
</script>
```

It gets the updates and all (nice!) but I've one problem: *it keeps creating new divs* inside the bigger one (empty divs). How can I avoid this?

**EDIT2:**

Nevermind, I've done!
Just add this line before the appendChild:

```
if(!$("#service"+i).length)
```

Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery you do not need to parse the `data` since it is already parsed as JSON when you set the `dataType: "json"`.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/MyApp/rest/display", 
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,service) {
            $("#service").append('<p>'+service+'</p>');
        });}, 
    dataType: "json" });
```

PS.  If that doesn't work, please post the JSON that is being returned by your AJAX call.

EDIT:  Here is the JSTL way of doing things:
Create a JSF or JSP that does NOT return a full HTML page but just what you want inside the `#service` div.  Lets call the page `doit.jsp`. Now we can just use ajax to put that in the `#service` div.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "doit.jsp",
    success: function(data) { $("#service").html(data); });
```

Comment: OMG! It worked! But I've one problem.. the script every 3 secs add me new divs. How can I update that ones? **EDIT:** later i'll try the jsp code! Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Enrichman: No problem.  if you want `$("#service").append('<p>'+service+'</p>');` to just replace instead of append you should use the html method `$("#service").html('<p>'+service+'</p>');`

Comment: I've a problem with that. The last service overwrite all the services.