# How to print array list data using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I am new to AJAX and JSON. I have an `ArrayList` which contains another `ArrayList` and I converted the whole array in to JSON object:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getRecords(@QueryParam("mobile_no") String mobilenumber) {
    UserActivityDelegate delegate = new UserActivityDelegate();
    List<AssessmentDTO> list = delegate.getLastFiveAssessment(mobilenumber
            .trim());
    if (list.isEmpty())
        return "Sorry....You have not attended any assessment";
    else {
        System.out.println(list);
        return (new Gson()).toJson(list);

    }
```

Now I want to know how can I retrieve or iterate the response object in JSP using ajax??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a JSON object (list of object) through Javascript and loop in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362724/parsing-a-json-object-list-of-object-through-javascript-and-loop-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax response you receive a response string you can convert that either to javascript list or json and iterate over them.

Like below:

```
jQuery.ajax({

              type: 'POST',
              url: your_url_string,
              data: 1=1 //params,
              async: false,
              success: function(response,textStatus){

                json= JSON.parse(response);
             },
                  error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
             });
```

then `json` object is what you need to take care of.